# Check cells in column C against column J to generate email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to check cells in column C against column J (which is my minimum stock quantity).

If column C is less than or equal to column J, I need Excel to generate and send an email (Outlook) to alert our purchasing department that specific items are running low.

The code is not triggering the email.

```vb
Dim xRg As Range


'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    'If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("J2:j2000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg < Target.Value Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
      "This is line 2"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "Email Address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"

        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is dodgy in this often seen email code. Here it has the potential of silently emptying the stockroom. Always remove when you see it just before `With xOutmail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't check correctly the actual stock quantity against the minimum value.

Try something like this:

```
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("C2:C2000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg <= xRg.Offset(0,7) Then
```

this is only for comparing the values, not checked the send of email.